# PySimpleGUI - Как сделать чтобы следущая часть кода выполнилась когда на экране появится изображение

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Всем привет, есть такой простой код:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time as sleep

x, y = sg.locateCenterOnScreen("images/img.png")
sleep(2)
sg.click(x, y)
```

Если изображения нет на экране, то выходит ошибка. Как можно сделать чтобы `sg.locateCenterOnScreen("images/img.png")` постоянно проверял есть ли на экране нужное изображение и если оно появилось, то кликал. Заранее спасибо

Comment: А какая ошибка? Там наверняка что-то не то в `x` и `y`, ну вот и проверяйте - что там. В цикле.

Comment: Дело не в ошибке, эта команда проверяет  есть ли изображение на экране и если его нет то выдает ошибку. Я просто не знаю как сделать чтобы оно постоянно проверяло наличие изображения без завершения программы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте "вечный" цикл, а исключение ловите и пропускайте:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time as sleep

while True:
    try:
        x, y = sg.locateCenterOnScreen("images/img.png")
        sleep(2)
        sg.click(x, y)
        # break
    except:
        pass
```

Если после успеха нужно прекратить цикл, то поставьте ещё `break` после `click`.

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня теперь такая проблема: ```try``` у меня вызывает функцию, которая вызывает другие функции. Все функции заканчиваются на одной. Как мне сделать чтобы при достижении этой функции цикл ```while```  заканчивался?

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то я же уже выше написал - поставьте `break` и цикл закончится. Я поставил закомментированный `break`, чтобы было понятнее.